# Пустой response getOffer() steam

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam-web-api

Здравствуйте.
Делаю бот для проверки, принят ли трейд человеком.

```
offers.getOffer({
    tradeofferid: row[i].tradeid2.toString()
}, function(error, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('er 0');
        weblogon();
        return;
    }
    console.log(body);
});
```

`row[i].tradeid2.toString()` - есть и возвращает верное значение текущего трейда.

Никаких ошибок нету, просто `console.log(body);` выводит `{ response { } }`.
Но суть в том, что с моим первым аккаунтом - работет, и колбэк есть, а с двумя другими - нет. 
Проверил уже все что можно. Ни на одном аккаунте нету бота в друзьях, у всех открыт инвентарь.

В чем может быть ошибка или как получать ответ со всех офферов по `tradeid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что API key для авторизации был сгенерирован не на аккаунте бота. Новый апи ключ помог.